# Why is my store so long in FireFox?

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, frontend

The site is http://bit.ly/1cFwCDC

I looked into the CSS and for some reason FF is adding stuff that actually isnt in the CSS like the following:

background: url("../themes/portland-copy/css/images/logo.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

when actually its background: transparent url(../themes/portland-copy/css/images/logo.jpg) repeat;

I tried adding the background-attachment: css and it did not fix it. I am at a loss.

I would really appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: This looks like the output from Firebug, which will list all the settings, including the defaults. Firefox isn't inventing new CSS. It's not clear from your question what the problem really is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your background image is waaaaayyy to big in size (lenght/width):
http://store.onlyjustbe.com/themes/portland-copy/css/images/logo.jpg

You should try to crop it, make it smaller (try 25px per 25px) and see if it changes something. Plus, your pages will load faster.

Comment: If this is your issue, user2981169, you have the same logo.img being declared in 2 places in your CSS. One in your portland.css file and another in your base.css file. Try deleting one of those in order to simply have the background image show once and be able to manipulate it.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave any properties out of the background shorthand property, the browser will revert those properties to default.

Firefox uses `rgb(0,0,0)` as shorthand for transparency, so this shouldn't be causing an issue.

If you want to stop the browser applying default values, you need to define all of the properties in your css shorthand, eg

```
background: url("../themes/portland-copy/css/images/logo.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a "View source" on your main page with both Chrome and Firefox and they both have the same CSS declaration as the one you mentioned above:

background: transparent url(images/logo.jpg) repeat;

Which then leads me to believe that you're probably using a browser plug-in such as Firebug or Web Developer, which do indeed add properties to your CSS, but should not affect your site at all. For me, in Firefox using Web Developer, the property shows up like this:

background: url("images/logo.jpg") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

Is this actually affecting the way your site looks? I highly doubt it since it looks to me that they are showing up the same in both Chrome and Firefox, but I digress to your response.

If your main concern for this issue is when you're editing the site using your plug-in, I would probably just recommend to ignore the fact that your FF plug-in will add declarations, since it really will not affect your site. Its only declaring defaults or other properties in different ways.

if your issue is that the background image is not being able to be controlled or deleted when you modify it using your plug-in, it may have to do with the fact that you have the background image showing up in 2 different css files. Once in portland.css and another in base.css. Try deleting one of these so you can work with the background image without any issues.